# Cannot get Full text in an element even after using Explicit - WebDriverWait in Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to coding, using stackoverflow for the first time. Wondering if I can get some help on this here.

I am trying to scrape the total no.of jobs given on this link.
https://jobs.bestbuy.com/bby?id=all_jobs&spa=1&s=req_id_num

## Following is my code.

```
import os
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as ec

os.environ['PATH'] += "/Users/monicayadav/PycharmProjects/pythonProject4/selenium/venv/bin"
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.implicitly_wait(30)


driver.get('https://jobs.bestbuy.com/bby?id=all_jobs&spa=1&s=req_id_num')
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
JobCountBESTBUY = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//p[contains(@class, 'font-wt-500 ng-binding')]"))).text

print(JobCountBESTBUY)
```

Output I am getting

```
jobs found

Process finished with exit code 0
```

I am getting only "job found" as a result , but I need this number instead 1,925

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution 1 - The easier one

Use [`time.sleep(seconds)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.sleep) to wait for the page to load the results completely. It's going to be something like the following. Don't forget to `import time`.

```py
import time

# ... Removed code for simplicity ...

driver.get('https://jobs.bestbuy.com/bby?id=all_jobs&spa=1&s=req_id_num')
time.sleep(10)
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
JobCountBESTBUY = wait.until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//p[contains(@class, 'font-wt-500 ng-binding')]"))).text

print(JobCountBESTBUY)
```

### Solution 2 - The faster one

On the other hand, `time.sleep` spends too much time waiting even though the text is ready already. Another approach is to search for the text itself like the following. The advantage is that as soon as a match is found the wait is over and is possible to return the number directly.

```py
import re

# ... Removed code for simplicity ...

driver.get('https://jobs.bestbuy.com/bby?id=all_jobs&spa=1&s=req_id_num')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ec.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//p[contains(@class, 'font-wt-500 ng-binding')]")))

# Matches `1,234`, `1`, `12`, `1,234,567`
r = re.compile(r'^([0-9,]+).*$')
JobCountBESTBUY = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
  lambda _: (e := driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//p[contains(@class, 'font-wt-500 ng-binding')]")) \
      and (m := r.match(e.text)) \
      and m.group(1)
)

print(JobCountBESTBUY)
```

**Output**

```
1,988
```

Comment: @Monica - as part of the support, if someone has provided you a qualified answer to your problem. The answer needs to be accepted and voted on, so others that search for a similar issue can use the knowledge base provided here.

Comment: @Iepsch - Wow!! Thats a huge help! Thanks so much